Signup and Login via SMS OTP using AWS cognito in Flutter
I am trying to integrate SMS OTP based signup and login flow using AWS Cognito with Flutter
I am able to send OTP to phone number for signUp method. But this sends OTP for signing up and not for login. Also, login is not possible without password.
Future<void> signUpWithPhoneVerification(
  String username,
  String password,
) async {
  await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
    username: username,
    password: password,
    options: SignUpOptions(
      userAttributes: <AuthUserAttributeKey, String>{
        AuthUserAttributeKey.phoneNumber: username,
      },
    ),
  );
}

Future<void> confirmSignUpPhoneVerification(
  String username,
  String otpCode,
) async {
  await Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp(
    username: username,
    confirmationCode: otpCode,
  );
}

Future<void> signInWithPhoneVerification(
  String username,
  String password,
) async {
  await Amplify.Auth.signIn(
    username: username,
    password: password,
  );
}

Future<void> signOutCurrentUser() async {
  final result = await Amplify.Auth.signOut();
  if (result is CognitoCompleteSignOut) {
    safePrint('Sign out completed successfully');
  } else if (result is CognitoFailedSignOut) {
    safePrint('Error signing user out: ${result.exception.message}');
  }
}

How to implement above functionalities without password and also for login?
Any help is appreciated.

Passwordless authentication will require you to implement CUSTOM_FLOW authentication flow. Here is great article how to do that - Implementing OTP based Phone auth in Amazon Cognito using Custom Auth Flow & Amplify

Thanks @Ankush Jain. Let me go through it.
